# comparing two strings to find the matching strings

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm working on my code as I'm searching for the matched strings in a sqlite3 database when compared with the list of strings from the arrays.

I need some help with writing the code, because I have no idea how to find the matched strings in a database when compared the list of strings from the arrays called `prog_id`.

When I try this:

```
#get access to the database
profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
con = database.connect(profilePath)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT button_ids, button_width FROM buttons')
buttonList = list()
buttons = cur.fetchall()

for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
    if CurrentRow == 375:
        if int(CurrentWidth) > 342:
            if int(pos_X) == 375:
               for buttons_id in zip(buttonList):
                   if int(buttons_id) == int(prog_id):
                      print buttons_id
                      print button_width
```

Here is the list of strings for the `buttons_id` in the arrays:

```
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3002',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3003',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3004',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3005',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3006',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3007',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3008',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3009',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3010',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3011',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3012',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3013',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3014',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3015',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3016',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3017',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3018',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3019',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3020',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3021',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3022',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3023',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3024',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3025',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3026',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3027',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3028',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3029',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3030',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3031',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3032',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3033',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3034',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3035',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3036',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3037',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3038',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3039',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3040',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3041',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3042',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3043',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3044',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3045',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3046',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3047',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3048',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3049',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3050',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3051',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3052',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3053',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3054',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3055',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3056',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3057',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3058',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3059',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3060',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3061',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3062',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3063',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3064',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3065',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3066',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3067',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3068',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3069',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3070',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3071',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3072',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3073',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3074',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3075',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3076',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3077',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3078',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3079',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3080',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3081',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3082',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3083',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3084',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3085',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3086',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3087',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3088',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3089',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3090',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3091',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3092',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3093',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3094',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3095',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3096',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3097',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3098',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3099',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3100',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3101',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3102',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3103',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3104',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3105',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3106',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3107',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3108',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3109',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3110',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3111',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3112',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3113',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3114',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3115',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3116',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3117',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3118',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3119',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3120',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3121',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3122',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3123',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3124',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3125',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3126',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3127',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3128',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3129',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3130',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3131',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3132',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3133',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3134',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3135',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3136',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3137',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3138',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3139',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3140',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3141',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3142',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3143',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3144',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3145',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3146',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3147',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3148',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3149',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3150',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3151',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3152',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3153',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3154',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3155',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3156',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3157',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3158',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3159',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3160',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3161',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3162',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3163',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3164',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3165',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3166',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3167',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3168',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3169',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3170',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3171',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3172',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3173',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3174',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3175',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3176',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3177',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3178',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3179',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3180',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3181',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3182',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3183',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3184',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3185',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3186',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3187',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3188',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3189',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3190',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3191',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3192',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3193',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3194',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3195',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3196',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3197',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3198',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3199',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3200',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3201',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3202',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3203',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3204',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3205',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3206',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3207',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3208',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3209',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3210',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3211',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3212',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3213',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3214',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3215',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3216',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3217',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3218',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3219',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3220',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3221',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3222',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3223',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3224',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3225',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3226',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3227',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3228',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3229',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3230',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3231',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3232',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3233',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3234',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3235',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3236',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3237',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3238',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3239',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3240',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3241',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3242',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3243',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3244',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3245',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3246',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3247',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3248',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3249',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3250',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3251',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3252',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3253',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3254',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3255',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3256',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3257',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3258',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3259',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3260',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3261',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3262',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3263',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3264',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3265',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3266',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3267',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3268',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3269',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3270',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3271',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3272',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3273',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3274',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3275',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3276',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3277',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3278',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3279',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3280',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3281',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3282',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3283',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3284',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3285',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3286',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3287',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3288',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3289',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3290',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3291',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3292',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3293',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3294',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3295',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3296',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3297',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3298',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3299',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3300',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3301',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3302',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3303',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3304',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3305',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3306',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3307',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3308',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3309',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3310',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3311',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3312',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3313',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3314',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3315',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3316',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3317',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3318',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3319',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3320',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3321',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3322',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3323',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3324',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3325',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3326',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3327',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3328',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3329',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3330',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3331',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3332',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3333',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3334',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3335',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3336',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3337',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3338',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3339',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3340',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3341',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3342',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3343',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3344',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3345',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3346',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3347',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3348',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3349',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3350',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3351',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3352',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3353',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3354',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3355',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3356',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3357',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3358',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3359',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3360',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3361',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3362',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3363',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3364',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3365',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3366',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3367',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3368',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3369',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3370',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3371',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3372',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3373',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3374',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3375',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3376',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3377',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3378',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3379',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3380',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3381',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3382',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3383',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3384',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3385',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3386',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3387',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3388',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3389',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3390',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3391',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3392',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3393',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3394',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3395',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3396',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3397',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3398',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3399',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3400',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3401',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3402',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3403',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3404',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3405',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3406',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3407',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3408',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3409',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3410',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3411',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3412',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3413',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3414',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3415',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3416',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3417',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3418',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3419',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3420',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3421',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3422',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3423',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3424',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3425',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3426',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3427',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3428',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3429',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3430',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3431',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3432',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3433',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3434',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3435',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3436',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3437',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3438',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3439',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3440',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3441',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3442',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3443',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3444',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3445',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3446',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3447',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3448',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3449',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3450',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3451',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3452',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3453',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3454',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3455',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3456',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3457',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3458',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3459',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3460',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3461',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3462',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3463',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3464',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3465',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3466',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3467',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3468',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3469',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3470',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3471',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3472',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3473',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3474',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3475',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3476',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3477',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3478',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3479',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3480',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3481',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3482',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3483',)
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3484',)
```

Here is the list of strings from `prog_id` arrays:

```
22:29:34 T:488  NOTICE: 3140
22:29:34 T:488  NOTICE: 3209
22:29:34 T:488  NOTICE: 3278
22:29:34 T:488  NOTICE: 3347
22:29:34 T:488  NOTICE: 3416
```

In my code that I wrote, I'm trying to compare the strings from the arrays of `prog_id` to see if it can find the matched strings in the database the arrays called `buttons_id`.

Can you please show me an example of how i can find the matched strings in the arrays when comparing with `prog_id` and `buttons_id` to see if i can find the matched strings to get the matched program ids?

Comment: Here is a good thread on this subject: [StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches). Although if your `prog_id` list is really small, it might be better to just use the database requests to do the matching (just look up each of them in the database). Anyway good luck!

Comment: @AbdAzrad thank you for your advice, why cant you post an example code of how i can use the database request to do the matching?

Comment: I would, but I don't have a database on hand to test it with and I don't use this enough to do it from memory, but you are already searching the database when you `cur.execute('SELECT button_ids, button_width FROM buttons')`, if you are only looking for 1 or 2 specific things, you could just narrow down the search for those things. Maybe something like this [example3](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group the button_id lines use the `prog` lines as keys, and check if the line after translating is in the dict if so append it to the list:

```
d = {k:[] for k in prog}

for line in button_ids:
    trans = line.translate(None,"',()")
    if trans in d:
         d[trans].append(line)
```

Or make prog_id a set and check in the translated line is in the set:

```
d = set(prog_id)

for line in button_ids:
    if line.translate(None,"',()"):
        print(line)
```

After str.translating your lines will be in the same format as the prog_id lines:

```
button_ids = ["22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3002',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3003',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3004',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3005',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3006',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3007',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3008',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3009',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3010',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3484',)"]


for line in button_ids:
    print line.translate(None,"',()")

22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3002
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3003
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3004
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3005
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3006
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3007
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3008
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3009
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3010
22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: 3484
```

So you will be able to compare, this will be way more efficient than using your nested for loops.

If you want a list of all matches:

```
st = set(prod_id)
matched = [line for line in button_ids if line.translate(None,"',()") in st]
```

If you are just matching on the last value the number in the tuple, you can extract the numbers into a set:

```
st = {line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in prog_id}
matched = [line for line in button_ids if line.rsplit(None,1)[1].translate(None,"',()") in st]

print(matched)
```

which outputs the following on your input provided:

```
["22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3140',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3209',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3278',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3347',)", "22:25:58 T:5624  NOTICE: ('3416',)"
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, when i try each of those code that you suggest me to use, none of them did find the matched strings from the database when I try to find the strings from the arrays of `prog_id`. do you have any idea why?

Comment: is the data exactly as you have posted? can you add a few lines but add them from `print(repr(line))`

Comment: Also do you want to match the full strings or just part if the strings?

Comment: I want to match the part of if strings. did you see what I have posted in my question with the list of strings from the arrays called `prog_id`??  you will see I have the list of ids in the database as I want to search for it to match it with `prog_id` to find the information i'm looking for.

Comment: You posted two sets of lines what do you want to match from those two sets of lines?