# Comparing elements in two lists when keeping duplicates is desired in Python

Tags: python, list

I'd like to compare two lists. I'd like to find elements in the first list that don't have a corresponding entry in the second list (order doesn't matter):

```
a = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'hi']
b = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye']
```

So I would like the output to be

```
c = ['hi']
```

since the first list has an extra 'hi' in it that doesn't appear in the second list.

If I do one of [the usual techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches), I can use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in a if x not in b]
```

which gives me `[]`, which is not what I want.

Things I've tried involve using the `set` operator, which have the same outcome, since that operation reduces the members of the list to uniqueness.

This seems like a simple operation. Do I need to enumerate each element in the lists first, and create tuples to compare? Do I need to put them into a Counter dict? All this sounds a little bit like overkill when I just want to a simple comparison of the elements in a list!

Comment: I think it's better if you add more test cases other than the one you put, for example, what's your expected output if `a=[1,2,2,2] and b=[1,2,3,4` ?...will `c=[2,2]` ?

Comment: I'd go through the 2nd list in a loop, find that element in the first list and then `pop` it.

Comment: I think it's actually the first list that needs to be looped through. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) objects support multi-set operations:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'hi']
>>> b = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye']
>>> Counter(a) - Counter(b)
Counter({'hi': 1})
```

Rebuilding a list from the Counter:

```
>>> list(counter.elements())
['hi']
```

Comment: dang thats an excellent answer ... I would not have thought of this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply without requiring any imports, with a while loop, checking each item:

```
a = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'hi']
b = ['hi', 'hi', 'bye']
c = []
while a:
    # Get first item (and remove).
    item = a.pop(0)
    if item in b:
        b.remove(item)
    else:
        c.append(item)

print c
```