# Why am I receiving an error when trying to compare two lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, string-comparison, list-comparison

I am trying to compare two lists on line `#12` and return matches found.

The lists contain one user selected number (`un`) and one of which have been randomly generated (`rn`).

For example, `[['1', '5', '3', '7']]` and `[['9', '6', '3', '2']]` would return `[3]`.

I am fairly new to python and was using the solution found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches), but am yet to have success with my code.

```
import random
import re

rn = []
un = []

Numbers = range(1000,9999)
RandomNumber = random.choice(Numbers)
RandomNumber = str(RandomNumber)

def check():
    x = set(rn) & set(un) #12
    print (x)

def numsys():
    b = list(RandomNumber)
    rn.append(b)
    print(rn)
    print(un)
    check()


def numval():
    while True:
        UserNum = (input("Please enter a 4 digit number: "))
        if re.match("^[0-9]{4,4}$", UserNum):
            a = list(UserNum)
            un.append(a)
            numsys()
            break        
numval()
```

Comment: The error means "you can't put a list inside a set". Use `un.extend(a)` instead of `un.append(a)`.

Comment: You can't do `set([['1', '1', '1', '1']])` since it's a list inside a list, so try `x = set(rn[0]) & set(un[0])` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using lists to pass the data around, use function parameters.

```
import random
import re

def check(random_number, user_number):
    print('random_number {}, user_number {}'.format(random_number, user_number))
    x = set(random_number).intersection(user_number)
    print(x)

def numval():
    random_num = str(random.choice(range(1000, 9999)))
    while True:
        user_num = (input("Please enter a 4 digit number: "))
        if re.match("^[0-9]{4,4}$", user_num):
            check(random_num, user_num)
            break

numval()
```

This avoids accessing global variables within the functions and is generally more readable. Doing this I was able to remove function `numsys()` because all it was doing was to unnecessarily fiddle with the global variables in order to make their values accessible in function `check()`.

One simplification was to keep the random and user numbers as strings. `set()` can be called on a string without requiring that it be first converted to a list. And only one of the strings needs to be explicitly converted to a set if you use `set.intersection()` instead of the `&` operator.

I also took the liberty of renaming the variables to conform with the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format) is used to construct a string by substituting fields (denoted by `{}` in this example) with values taken from the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast a list to a string back and forth, the result wouldn't be the original string. It would be a list containing the characters of the representation of the original string.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = str(a)
>>> c = list(b)
>>> c
['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']
```

Don't do such castings, and if you have to, use `','.join(map(str, a))` to cast to string, and `list(map(int, b.split(',')))` to cast to list back.