# How to check if value is not in both lists

Tags: python, list

```
a=[1,2,5]
b=[3,4]
x=8
res= (x not in a) and (x not in b)   #True
```

But what is the nice and fastest way to check it?

Comment: That's pretty much it.

Comment: I mean, if you wanted, you could use `all`, but for just two lists your current approach is already very readable.

Comment: If you have a lot of values, and your lists are fairly large, then you should convert your lists to sets.

Comment: The way you have written it should be fast enough.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new and I thought python may have some nice magic syntaxis for this like in many other cases)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: The way to do it is to realize that a list membership check is O(n) whereas it is O(1) for sets; if order is not important, use sets instead.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are large, and you really want to check that `x` isn't in _both_ `a` and `b` rather than in _either_ `a` or `b`, then it may be more efficient to create a set of the intersection of `a` and `b`, especially if you have lots of `x`s to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution is perfectly fine and readable, you can make it more generic by allowing a variable number of list and checking if a given element is in any of them by wrapping it in a function:

```
>>> def not_in_any(*lists, key=None):
        for lst in lists:
            if key in lst:
                return False
        return True

>>> not_in_any([2, 5, 7], [8, 9, 23], [34, 56, 78], [32, 91, 6], key=32)
False
>>> not_in_any([2, 5, 7], [8, 9, 23], [34, 56, 78], [31, 91, 6], key=32)
True
>>>
```

Note however that Python already provides a built in function - `any()` which already provides the behavior of the for-loop in our function:

```
def not_in_any(key=None, *lists):
    not any(key in l for l in lists)
```

Comment: Or just `not any(key in l for l in lists)`, or `all(key not in l for l in lists)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well yup, that works too :|  Just was trying to be more verbose for the OP's sake. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,5]
b=[3,4]
x=8
all(x not in i for i in (a, b))
```

OR:

```
from itertools import chain
x not in chain(a, b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Other approach is concat and check:-

```
a=[1,2,5]
b=[3,4]
x=8
res= x not in a+b  #True
```

Comment: That needlessly creates a new list.

Comment: yes, it is convenient to single check or comparision

Comment: I don't understand why your response to criticism is to agree with a fabricated compliment...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 i agree as i am suggesting a alternate, that depand on situation whether we are going to use it or not. But it is a alternate.