# pandas return columns in dataframe that are not in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
'A' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
'B' : [100, 200, 300, 400],
'C' : [2, 3, 4, 5] 
                   })

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
'B' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
'C' : [100, 200, 300, 400],
'D' : [2, 3, 4, 5] 
                  })
```

Now if I utilize pandas .isin function I can do something nifty like this

```
>>> print df_2.columns.isin(df_1.columns)
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Columns `B` and `C` from `df_2` exist in `df_1` while `D` doesn't

My question is: does anyone know of a way to return the columns' labels for columns that exist in df_2 but not in df_1

something like this

```
array([u'D'], dtype=string)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Pandas index object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Index.html) have set-like properties, so you can directly do:

```
df_2.columns.difference(df_1.columns)
Index([u'D'], dtype='object')
```

You can also use operators like `&|^` to compute intersection, union and symmetric difference:

```
df_1.columns & df_2.columns
Index([u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')

df_1.columns | df_2.columns
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], dtype='object')

df_1.columns ^ df_2.columns
Index([u'A', u'D'], dtype='object')
```

There use to be the `-`operator for difference, now deprecated:

```
df_2.columns - df_1.columns
FutureWarning: using '-' to provide set differences with Indexes is deprecated, use .difference()
Index([u'D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Nice usage of set-like properties on pandas Index objects +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Numpy solution with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
a = np.setdiff1d(df_2.columns, df_1.columns)
print (a)
['D']
```

Pandas solution with [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
a = df_2.columns.difference(df_1.columns)
print (a)
Index(['D'], dtype='object')
```

Another pandas methods are [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html), 
[`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`symmetric_difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html)
:

```
print (df_2.columns.intersection(df_1.columns))
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')

print (df_2.columns.union(df_1.columns))
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')

print (df_2.columns.symmetric_difference(df_1.columns))
Index(['A', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

And numpy functions are [`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), [`union1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) and [`setxor1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html):

```
print (np.intersect1d(df_2.columns, df_1.columns))
['B' 'C']

print (np.union1d(df_2.columns, df_1.columns))
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']

print (np.setxor1d(df_2.columns, df_1.columns))
['A' 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

here it is buddy

```
set(df_2.columns).difference(df_1.columns)
Out[76]: {'D'}
```

Comment: why set? it is not necessary  I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
set(df_2.columns.values) - set(df_1.columns.values)
```

which returns a set containing column labels of columns in `df_2` but not in `df_1`.