# Is there a way to get the element that belong only to a dataset d1 and not to another one d2, with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two datasets d1 and d2, where the d1 columns are:

d1_columns {X,Y,**Z,T**}

and for d2 :

d2_columns{X,Y,**L,P**}

Is there a function f such that:

f(d1,d2) = **{Z,T}** or equivalently: f(d1,d2) = **{L,P}** ?

Comment: @Alonso        Welcone to SO, it seem your question is already answered here [columns in data frame that are not in the other data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028969/pandas-return-columns-in-dataframe-that-are-not-in-other-dataframe). Does this answer your question.? Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following Code -

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[2,5,4,7,8],'C':[4,1,7,5,6],'D':[2,5,4,7,8]}) #First Dataframe

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[2,5,4,7,8],'E':[5,6,7,4,4],'F':[5,7,8,9,4]}) #Second Dataframe

new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1) # Concat the dataframes

new_df[list(set(new_df.columns).difference(df1.columns))] # Gives us Columns (E,F)
new_df[list(set(new_df.columns).difference(df2.columns))] # Gives us Columns (C.D)

Answer (score 0):

In this case first add both the dataframes and then subtract the other.

Eg : A = ( a,b,c,d )  , B = ( a,b,e,g ).   Here I mean to say that a,b,c,d,e,f are the column names.

So , if you want column ( c,d ) only , then do

1. C = A + B , then ,
2. C = C - B and hence you will be left with columns ( c,d ) only.

Likewise you can do for ( e,g ) columns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think that should work. But I don't know how to implement the subtraction with pandas. How would you code it?