# Compare occurrences of shared items between lists

Tags: python

Ok, for a fun project I'm working on in order to learn some python I'm hitting a wall with what should be a basic task: I need to compare lists for the times items shared among the lists occur in each list. Using
    `shared_items = set(alist).intersection(blist)
gives me the items shared`betwen the lists, but it does not tell me, how often those items occur in each list.
I tried loops like this for example:

```
def the_count(alist,blist):
    c = 0
    for x in alist:
        for y in blist:
            if x == y:
                c += 1
    return c
```

but that doesn't do the trick.

Another attempt was to use Counter:

```
c = Counter(alist)
b = Counter(blist)
```

But trying to loop over the Counter results failed too, last try was

```
a = Counter(alist)
b = Counter(blist)
for key, val in a:
   if key in b:
    val1 = b[key]
    if val < val1:
        print b[key]
    else:
        print a[key]
```

Comment: Look at the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: @Idan Meyer Thanks, but that only adresss how to get the shared elements, not how to count their occurrences in the lists. Actually I had learned from that answer how to use set intersection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it using the set `intersection`. Since that gives you the common elements amongst both lists, all you have to do now is loop over that and count the elements. One way could be:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
list2 = [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 2, 7, 8]
shared = set(list1).intersection(list2)

# Now, loop over the elements and create a dictionary using a generator.
# The key will be the shared element, and the value would be a tuple
# which corresponds to the counts of the first list and the second list, respectively
counts = {num:(list1.count(num), list2.count(num)) for num in shared}
```

`counts` now contains:

```
{
    0: (1, 1), 
    1: (2, 2), 
    2: (3, 2), 
    3: (3, 1), 
    4: (1, 1)
}
```

This can further be abstracted into a function similar to:

```
def count_shared_elements(list1, list2):
    shared = set(list1).intersection(list2)
    return {num:(list1.count(num), list2.count(num)) for num in shared}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list (dict) as jrd1 pointed  comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
>>> list2 = [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0, 2, 7, 8]
>>> {i:(list1.count(i), list2.count(i)) for i in set(list1) & set(list2)}
{0: (1, 1), 1: (2, 2), 2: (3, 2), 3: (3, 1), 4: (1, 1)}
```

Comment: This is not a list comprehension - it's actually a dictionary comprehension. Also, using the bitwise `&` operator is actually slower (only marginally, though) in this case as each list has to be converted to a set before any comparison can be done. Compare that functionality to using a set intersection which only requires at least one `set` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already correct to dict as you point, on my Moto Z the bench was very marginally indeed,  running 10.000 times:
my code --> 2.2313189506530762
your code-> 2.1449000835418701

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the answers linked in the question comments, another way to do this would be like this:

```
for a in alist:
    c+= blist.count(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to get the unique items from two lists and check the count of those distinct numbers in each list.

```
for distinct_num in set(alist + blist):
    print(alist.count(distinct_num))
    print(blist.count(distinct_num))
```

Comment: Your code has some minor errors - the first `print` statement is missing a close parentheses, and the second `print` and `count` statements are missing those closing parentheses as well.

Comment: You should be aware that this only counts all the unique elements of the *union* of the two lists, not the common elements!