# Python-How to combine list of lists Iff there is something common in those lists?

Tags: python

Hey i need some help regarding list of list. For example i have a list :

```
parentList = [[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
               ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
               ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""]],
              [["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]]
```

Here "**parentList**" is one list containing multiple sublists

```
A=[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
   ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
   ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
   ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""]]
```

and

```
B= [["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
    ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]
```

I want to merge these two lists of lists within **parentList** if there is some common list between them. As you can clearly see in the example, that there is one list common in between A and B.
I want the output as 
```

```
parentList = [[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
               ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
               ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""],
               ["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]]
```

**Note**:- there can be multiple sublists in "parentList" with nothing is common to any sublist. Such unique sublists should retain their structure.

Comment: fix the formatting please, impossible to read the question

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388836/6464041)

Comment: Are the lowest level lists all the same length?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide fixed that. I hope it's readable now

Comment: @morsecodist Nope. lengths can be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another rather complicated approach that may suits your needs:

```
parentList = [[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
               ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
               ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""]],
              [["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
               ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]]

# Gather all elements of every sublist in a list along with the indice of the sublist e.g [0,1] of the parentList that they belong to.
elements = []
for subListIndex, subList in enumerate(parentList):
   for elem in subList:
      elements.append([subListIndex, elem])

# Check if two elements of different subList index have the same list and if they do, merge the two subLists.
for i in range(len(elements)):
   for j in [k for k in range(len(elements)) if not k==i]:
      if elements[i][1] == elements[j][1] and not elements[i][0]==elements[j][0]:
         parentList[elements[i][0]].extend(parentList[elements[j][0]])
         parentList[elements[j][0]] = [] # Needed in order to avoid reproducing already existing merged lists.

# Clear any empty subList.
parentList = [l for l in parentList if not l==[]]

# Print the final result.
for subList in parentList:
   for elem in subList:
      print(elem)
   print()
```

Output:

```
['69', '742', '180', '760', '05.07.2007', '']
['69', ' 768', '180', '785', '05.07.2007', '']
['69', '794', '180', '811', '05072007', '']
['69', '768', '180', '785', '05.07.2007', '']
['69', '742', '180', '760', '05.07.2007', '']
['68', '717', '180', '735', '05.07.2007', '']
```

Comment: `parentList[elements[j][0]].clear()`   there is no method `clear()`

Comment: This is definitely what i needed. Thankyou :')

Comment: @Sanket thank you for pointing out. I edited my question. It did work though, using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple iterative worst case O(n3) solution would be to iterative over the lists and compare and merge if the match is found.

```
A=[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
   ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
   ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
   ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""]]

B= [["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
    ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]

def should_merge(A, B):
   if any((b in A) for b in B):
        return True

def merge(A, B):
  result = A
  for b in B:
    if (b not in A):
      result.append(b)
  return result

if should_merge(A, B):
  print(merge(A, B))
```

Prints this:

```
[['69', '742', '180', '760', '05.07.2007', ''], 
['69', ' 768', '180', '785', '05.07.2007', ''], 
['69', '794', '180', '811', '05072007', ''], 
['69', '768', '180', '785', '05.07.2007', ''], 
['68', '717', '180', '735', '05.07.2007', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[["69", "742", "180","760", "05.07.2007", ""],
   ["69"," 768", "180", "785", "05.07.2007", ""], 
   ["69", "794","180","811","05072007",""], 
   ["69", "768", "180","785", "05.07.2007", ""]]

B= [["69", "742", "180", "760", "05.07.2007", ""], 
    ["68", "717", "180", "735", "05.07.2007", ""]]


found = False

for a in A:
    if a in B:
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print(A+B)
```

Not most efficient one, since you are searching, but I think it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just have idea with this

**Try this:-**

```
if any((x in A) for x in B):
    parentList.append([A,B])
print(parentList)
```