# How to count the total number of similar elements in two lists occuring at the same index?

Tags: python

Let the two lists be

```
x = [0,1,2,2,5,2,1,0,1,2]
y = [0,1,3,2,1,4,1,3,1,2]
```

How to find the similar elements in these two lists in python and print them.
What I am doing-

```
for i, j in x, y:
   if x[i] == y[j]:
      print(x[i], y[j])
```

I want to find elements like x[0], y[0] and x[1], y[1] etc.
This does not work, I am new to python. 
I want to find the exact index at which the elements are common.
I want to find the index 0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9; because the elements at these indices are equal

Comment: Are you basically after: `sum(a == b for a, b in zip(x, y))` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: This would find the common elements, not the exact index...

Comment: @maya then be more precise about the result you want.

Comment: Python list indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: "similar" is not the same as "equal".

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0,1,2,2,5,2,1,0,1,2]
y = [0,1,3,2,1,4,1,3,1,2]

for i in range(len(x)):
  if x[i] == y[i]:
    print(i)
```

Note: if the lists are not in the same len, this will produce index out of bound error

Comment: @maya, no it's not, are you using python3?

Comment: Could you write it in the form of for loops(decompressed)

Comment: It would also not work for the case, for i in x, y: , right?

Comment: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" is the error

Comment: @maya `for i, j in list` require ti list elements to be separate to two values i.e list = [[a,b],[c,d]...]`  so `zip(list1,list2)` will return that type of list as for the error you can iterate over the shorter list like `range(min(len(x),len(y)))`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the exact index at which the elements are common.

`enumerate` the zipped sequence:

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,2,5,2,1,0,1,2]
>>> y = [0,1,3,2,1,4,1,3,1,2]
>>> [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(x, y)) if a == b]
[0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9]
```

`zip(x, y)` will give you pairs of elements from `x` and `y` at the same index:

```
>>> zip(x, y)
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (2, 2), (5, 1), (2, 4), (1, 1), (0, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Enumerating this sequence gives you the index of each item:

```
>>> list(enumerate(zip(x, y)))
[(0, (0, 0)), (1, (1, 1)), (2, (2, 3)), (3, (2, 2)), (4, (5, 1)), (5, (2, 4)), (6, (1, 1)), (7, (0, 3)), (8, (1, 1)), (9, (2, 2))]
```

As you can see, the elements have a (int, (int, int)) structure. These tuples are unpacked with the `for i, (x, y) in ...` syntax in the list comprehension. 
Finally, we only care about the ones where the (int, int) part holds the same integer at both positions (`if a == b`) and out of these matches, we only take the index `i`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you tell me where was the problem in my code..the simplified version

Comment: @maya `for i, j in x, y:` does not work because you are implictly trying the assignments `i, j = [0, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]` and `i, j = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2]` where the right hand side has too many values to unpack into two names `i` and `j`.

Comment: So, if I write nested for loops, it would still not keep track of the exact sequence as it would loose the indices, is it possible to do this without zip?

Comment: @maya "is it possible to do this without zip" <- yes, with `for index in range(len(x)) ...` but this is considered bad style.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And for i in x,y: gives an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list", even though i= [0, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2] and j = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2], why is that. Is it because i can't take two values, and if we created a tuple instead it would store the values?

Comment: @maya it's time to stop the follow up questions now. We usually deal with one question per topic here.