# Find sequences of words in sublists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, lcs

In some NLP task I have a nested list of strings:

```
    [['Start', 'двигаться', 'другая', 'сторона', 'света', 'надолго', 'скоро'], 
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'другая', 'сторона', 'света', 'чтобы', 'посмотреть'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'новая', 'планета'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет', 'израильский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'на'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
     ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'и']]
```

I need an algorithm to find **two or more** elements, which are common **for two or more** sublists and make a single element from them. in my example, `'Start', 'двигаться'` is common for all elements, so it should become single string. `'сторона', 'света', 'надолго'` is common for two elements, so it become single string. `'сторона', 'признание'` is common for 5 elements, so it become single string. If there are no common elements left, just add the rest elements as a single string.
Desired output:

```
    [['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро'], 
     ['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'новая планета'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот на'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот Голанский'],
     ['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'и']]
```

So far I tried some loops and element comparison:

```
for elem,next_elem in zip(lst, lst[1:]+[lst[0]]):
    if elem[0] == next_elem[0] and elem[1] == next_elem[1] and elem[2] == next_elem[2]:
        elem[0:3] = [' '.join(elem[0:3])]

    if elem[0] == next_elem[0] and elem[1] == next_elem[1]:
        elem[0:2] = [' '.join(elem[0:2])]
```

But I don't think that's the right way. Sets are also not an option since there can be multiple occurrences of one element in the sublist.
I checked other LCS topics but didn't find a solution. Any working algorithm that does the job will be great, efficiency is unimportant at the moment. Some more examples:

```
[[a,b,c,d],
 [a,b,d,e,f]]
```

Should become:

```
[[ab,cd],
 [ab,def]]
```

Since `a,b` are common element, and `cd, def` just become single element.

```
[[a,b,c,d,e,g],
[a,b,c,d,g,h],
[a,b,h,h,i]]
```

Should become:

```
[[ab,cd,eg],
 [ab,cd,gh],
 [ab,hhi]]
```

Since `ab` and `cd` are cannon for two or more sublists

And:

```
[[a,b,c],
 [a,b,d]]
```

Becomes:

```
[[ab, c],
 [ab, d]]
```

Since `c, d` are not common elements

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches).

Comment: Waht if you have `[[a, b], [a, b, c], [b, c]]`? Also, why is `'и'` joined to the strings before, but `'высот'` is not?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for your reply! In that case output will be `[[a b], [a b c], [b c]]` since 'c' will be single left element and should be added to previous sequence and 'b c' is unique element.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use hashmaps key:word, value: Integer as counter, starts as 0. (This is dictionary in python). For every line, hash each values and increase the counter. At the end, for every word that has a counter of 2 or more, you concatenate them.

I've left out code and the part where you concatenate only strings with same counter, and repitition since this seems like homework.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with creating a [prefix-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) representing your lists:

```
lists = [['Start', 'двигаться', 'другая', 'сторона', 'света', 'надолго', 'скоро'], 
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'другая', 'сторона', 'света', 'чтобы', 'посмотреть'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'новая', 'планета'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет', 'израильский'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'на'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот', 'Голанский'],
         ['Start', 'двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'и']]

tree = {}
end = "END"
for lst in lists:
    d = tree
    for x in lst:
        d = d.setdefault(x, {})
    d[end] = {}
```

Result (here, `END` marks where a sentence has ended):

```
{'Start': {'двигаться': {'другая': {'сторона': {'света': {'надолго': {'скоро': {'END': {}}},
                                                          'чтобы': {'посмотреть': {'END': {}}}}}},
                         'новая': {'планета': {'END': {}}},
                         'сторона': {'признание': {'END': {},
                                                   'высот': {'Голанский': {'END': {}},
                                                             'на': {'END': {}},
                                                             'оккупировать': {'END': {}}},
                                                   'и': {'END': {}},
                                                   'суверенитет': {'израильский': {'END': {}}}}}}}}
```

Now, you can recursively traverse that tree, and whenever a node has only a single child (a sub-dict with just a single element), join those nodes.

```
def join(d, pref=[]):
    if end in d:
        yield [' '.join(pref)] if pref else []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(v) == 1:
            for x in join(v, pref + [k]): # add node to prefix
                yield x                   # yield next segment
        else:
            for x in join(v, []):         # reset prefix
                yield [' '.join(pref + [k])] + x # yield node + prefix and next
```

Output is not *exactly* as in your question, but very close. It will join all the parts that have only a single child in the tree, i.e. afterwards segments should be maximal while no segment is part of a longer segment.

```
>>> for x in join(tree):
...     print(x)
...
['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро']
['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть']
['Start двигаться', 'новая планета']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'суверенитет израильский']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'на']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'оккупировать']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'высот', 'Голанский']
['Start двигаться', 'сторона признание', 'и']
```

Here's an illustration of the tree-based approach. Colors indicate parts without any branching that will be merged; end-nodes are bold (those do not have to be leaf-nodes).

[image]

Comment: @AlexNikitin Thanks, although I have the feeling that `join` function is more complicated than necessary. Will revisit later...

Comment: Broke the algorithm by changing `новая планета` to `сторона планета`:
`[['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'надолго скоро'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'другая сторона света', 'чтобы посмотреть'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона планета'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'суверенитет израильский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот на'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот оккупировать'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание', 'высот Голанский'],
 ['Start двигаться', 'сторона', 'признание и']]`

Comment: @AlexNikitin Interesting... I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @AlexNikitin Can you check again? At least I can't reproduce that problem any longer.

Comment: Thanks again, visualisation is really great! It seems that there is some problem in tree building. if I change `'новая', 'планета'` to `'сторона', 'планета'` in input, `'сторона', 'признание'` become separated elements in the output. can reproduce with similar cases, I double-checked.

Comment: @AlexNikitin Ah, okay, then I misread your previous comment (or rather the modification you made). But that would be to be expected using this approach, as then the `сторона` node has more than one children. TBH, I think I still haven't entirely understood your rules for joining segments. E.g., why to join `'высот на'`? Could you elaborate again? (preferrably in the question itself, not in this comment thread)

Comment: Thanks for your time! 
In my post there is: algorithm to find **two or more elements**, which are common for two or more sublists. so single element can't become node. and about `'высот на'`: If there are no common elements left, just add the rest elements as a single string. since `высот` is a single common element, it can't form node, so it just become one string with the rest words in sequence.
Thanks again, you really help our little project!

Comment: @AlexNikitin I still don't understand all of this, and to be honest, I am not sure that you yourself really understand what you want _exactly_ -- if I'm wrong, please elaborate further _in the question itself_, preferrably with some more examples. For instance, how should `[[a, b, c], [a, b, d],[ a, b, e]]` be grouped? As [[ab, c], [ab, d], [ab,e]]`, or `[[abc], [abd], [abe]]`, as there should be no single elements?

Comment: Edited the part with single elements. It will be more easy to add them after building the tree, anyway. Added more examples, hope it helps!

Comment: In simple words I can say that we need a tree as you created, but with minimal length of node of 2 elements. If there are no 2 or more common elements left, add the rest as single element.