# Comparing values in a a df column, extracting matches in to 1 column and differences into another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, difflib, fuzzywuzzy

Hi and thanks in advance, new to python and pandas.

1. I have a df column `df['name']`, this large data consists of product names all with different lengths,letters, numbers, punctuation and spacing.
   This makes each name a unique value this makes it hard to find variants of some of the products.
2. I then split the column values by spacing.

   `df['name'].str.split(" ",expand = True)`

I Found some code in this Question but I dont know how to apply it to iterate and compare through a list as its using variables and 2 list and I just have one list.
[How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)?

`Not the most efficient one, but by far the most obvious way to do it is:
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
set(a) & set(b)
{5}
if order is significant you can do it with list comprehensions like this:
[i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i == j]
[5]`

3. What im trying to achieve is:

data set

`1.star t-shirt-large-red
2.star t-shirt-large-blue
3.star t-shirt-small-red
4.beautiful rainbow skirt small
5.long maxwell logan jeans- light blue -32L-28W
6.long maxwell logan jeans- Dark blue -32L-28W`

-compare all items in the list against each other and find the longest string match. Example: products:1,2,3  have matching partial strings
    `result 
      COL1                             COL2         COL3    COL4
      1[star t-shirt]                  [large]      [red]    NONE
      2[star t-shirt]                  [large]      [blue]   NONE
      3[star t-shirt]                  [small]      [red]    NONE
      4[beautiful rainbow skirt small] NONE         NONE     NONE
      5[long maxwell logan jeans]      [light blue] [32L]  [28W]
      6[long maxwell logan jeans]      [Dark blue]  [32L]  [28W]`

Can anyone point me in the right direction in how to achieve my end result. I researched about modules like fuzzywuzzy and diffilab but don't know how to apply it also regex but im not sure how I would achieve string matching in a list with so many different formats?
Please when responding can you explain it step by step so I can understand what your doing and why. Just for learning purposes 
Thank you in advance again.

Comment: How do you decide whether or not to separate `[light blue]`? Although humans know this is color, but program does not know. They will be separated according to your space separator.

Comment: I was think with the "-" maybe but im not sure if thats possible. Also if your comparing to the previous string would it output the matched  longest string .

Comment: Maybe split by the dashes first then do a match comparison, then do another split by white spaces and match comparsion

Comment: @giser_yugang do you have any ideas, I think might have to do this sequentially but doing a number of splitting and sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is really  big. I think you have to reconsider the purpose of doing so.

In the first step, each row corresponds to each other.

```
df['onkey'] = 1
df1 = pd.merge(df[['name','onkey']],df[['name','onkey']], on='onkey')
df1['list'] = df1.apply(lambda x:[x.name_x,x.name_y],axis=1)
```

The second step is to  find the longest string match.

```
from os.path import commonprefix
df1['COL1'] = df1['list'].apply(lambda x:commonprefix(x))
```

Remove rows that not find string match.

```
df1['COL1_num'] = df1['COL1'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
df1 = df1[(df1['COL1_num']!=0)]
```

Find the shortest match.

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('name_x')['COL1_num'].idxmin()]
```

Merge df and df1.

```
df = df.rename(columns ={'name':'name_x'})
df = pd.merge(df,df1[['name_x','COL1']],on='name_x',how ='left')
```

We can look data like this:

```
                                         name_x  onkey                           COL1
0                         star t-shirt-large-red      1                  star t-shirt-
1                        star t-shirt-large-blue      1                  star t-shirt-
2                         star t-shirt-small-red      1                  star t-shirt-
3                  beautiful rainbow skirt small      1  beautiful rainbow skirt small
4  long maxwell logan jeans- light blue -32L-28W      1     long maxwell logan jeans- 
5   long maxwell logan jeans- Dark blue -32L-28W      1     long maxwell logan jeans-
```

As you can see, we have found the longest string match.

Handle the common string, and we separate the remaining string.

```
df['len'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
df['other'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.name_x[x.len:],axis=1)
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1]=='-' else x)
df['other'] = df['other'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-'))
```

Finally, we will concat them.

```
df = df[['COL1','other']]
df = pd.concat([df['COL1'],df['other'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
```

The result:

```
                            COL1            0     1    2
0                   star t-shirt        large   red  NaN
1                   star t-shirt        large  blue  NaN
2                   star t-shirt        small   red  NaN
3  beautiful rainbow skirt small                NaN  NaN
4       long maxwell logan jeans  light blue    32L  28W
5       long maxwell logan jeans   Dark blue    32L  28W
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding and showing me step by step. But essentially  this method would take a long time in regards to whole it would take to complete due it comparing every single row by one row  and going down the column.

Comment: According to your needs, I think you can only do so.

Comment: ok make sense.  I did try it out on my data set but seems to be pulling the first letter of the string.