# Getting a word from list in python

Tags: python, list

My list is `['text1',  'text2', 'text3']` so one so.

How can I extract only `text1` or `text2`?

Tried with re but can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Hi there welcome to SO. Your question is unclear: Why do "text1" and "text2" qualify for extraction? What have you tried with `re` (include what you've tried)? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54251399/edit) your question with these details. Thanks. :-)

Comment: you can certainly extract using re - regular expression. see the answer below.

Comment: @Satheesh two answers have been provided to your question. Please take your time to see which best works for you and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

You can access the elements in the list by specifying their index between square brackets

```
my_list[0] # "a"
my_list[1] # "b"
my_list[2] # "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter by using the filter function with regular expression.
Like this:

```
import re

mylist =  ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'] 
r = re.compile("text2")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, mylist)) 
print(newlist)
```

result here:

```
['text2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_with_items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]

list_with_search_items = ["item2", "item3"]

for item in list_with_search_items:
    if item in list_with_items:
        print(item)
```

output:

```
item2
item3
```

Its a simple list approach. If your `list_with_items` and `list_with_search_items` have the same length, then you can use the set approach as here: [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)