# How a search one list and see if all those items are in second list and then print (if any) all the missing elements and how many there are?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am currently learning python. I would like to know how can I compare two list. I have two lists:

```
days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'friday']
new_days = ['weekend', 'wednesday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday','thursday']
```

How can I write, I'm assuming a loop, a code to see if all the elements from the days list are in the new_days list and then if there are any missing elements from the days list that aren't in the new_days list print out how many are missing and print out the ones that are missing? Would I use the all() function to compare the two to begin with?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used the set() but it seems like that just does a Union.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: Saying "I used set()" doesn't really tell us much.  _How_ did you use it?  Show us the code, and explain how those results aren't what you wanted.

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. I did the set(): @vurmux (set(days) - set(new_days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just interested in finding the difference between both list you could use the following code:

```
days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'friday']
new_days = ['weekend', 'wednesday', 'saturday', 'sunday', 'monday','thursday']
difference = list(set(days) - set(new_days))
```

how this helps

Comment: This was very helpful! So using the set for both lists and then converting them into list to find the different. Thank you so much! But how can I loop this to check each item and then when finishing checking all items print?

Comment: @Abdul-AzizMuhammad I'm happy that this helped! if you could click on the grey tick near the answer to validate it that would be great!

Comment: My only question is why use list if they are already in list format?

Comment: We use list because we have convert both variables into sets using set(). In order to get the final result as a list we have to use list().