# count occurrences of list items in second list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6

```py
a = list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
b = list([1, 3, 6, 9])
```

How do I count the number of times an item in list be occurs in list a?

The above example should return a value of 4.

Whilst writing this question, I thought of the following (which appears to work)

```py
a = list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
b = list([1, 3, 6, 9])
c = 0
for n in b:
    if n in a:
        c += 1
        continue
print (c)
```

But there must be a neater way using list comparisons or something?

Comment: Is `b` guaranteed to be unique values? As you could just do `len(set(b).intersection(a))`...

Comment: You don't need to stick a `list` call around all of your lists.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of occurrences of a specific item? e.g. How often do 1 occur in list a. Or do you want to count how many same items both lists have?

Comment: @Jon Clements - both lists, in this case, are unique.

Comment: @user2357112 - thank you, I'm very new to py

Comment: @Uli Sotschok - count the number of items that are the same in both lists.

Comment: `continue ` is redundant in the above code

Comment: Thanks @Nick.  I had realised that after posting.  Should have edited really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of elements that are in both lists (and you don't need to know how many times they occur in the other list) you can just use:

```
count = len(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

Or identically:

```
count = len(set(a) & set(b))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use built-in `sum`:

```
sum(i in b for i in a)
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's not possible, as yet, to know exactly the data the OP has

Answer (score 3):

Simple way using `set`:

```
>>> len(set(a) & set(b))
4
```

This is an old question, take a look to:
[How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: The difference between this question and the one you link to is that I don't want to return the matching values, I just need to count how many there are.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I only say that compare lists (after you can count or not) is an old issue :) I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm so new to py, that sometimes I struggle to fish out the relevant code as a lot of examples often do something different than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I've accepted both yours, and @Chris 's answer above as solutions to my question.  I shall pay with both to see which suits me best.  Thank you.

Comment: This is just exactly the same as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this just in one line:

```
s = sum(a.count(i) for i in b if i in a)
```

`s` will be `4` as output.
Also, it supports duplicate items in `a`.

Comment: This is unnecessarily inieficient, as you are computing the same count on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few variations that count duplicates and ignore all values that aren't in b.

```py
from collections import Counter
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
a = [1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
b = [1, 3, 6, 9]

counts = Counter()
# make counts order match b order
for item in b:
    counts[item] = 0
for item in a:
    if item in b:
        counts[item] += 1
print("in 'b' order")
print([(k, v) for k, v in counts.items()])
print("in descending frequency order")
print(counts.most_common())
print("count all occurrences in a of elements that are also in b")
print(sum(counts.values()))



python count_b_in_a.py
in 'b' order
[(1, 3), (3, 1), (6, 2), (9, 1)]
in descending frequency order
[(1, 3), (6, 2), (3, 1), (9, 1)]
count all occurrences in a of elements that are also in b
7
```

Responding to your comment about performance, here's a comparison between scanning a list and scanning a set in Python:

```py
import datetime

def timestamp():
    return datetime.datetime.now()


def time_since(t):
    return (timestamp() - t).microseconds // 1000


a = list(range(1000_000))
b = set(a)
iterations = 10
t = timestamp()
for i in range(iterations):
    c = 974_152 in a
print("Finished {iterations} iterations of list scan in {duration}ms"
      .format(iterations=iterations, duration=time_since(t)))
t = timestamp()
for i in range(iterations):
    c = 974_152 in b
print("Finished {iterations} iterations of set scan in {duration}ms"
      .format(iterations=iterations, duration=time_since(t)))

python scan.py
Finished 10 iterations of list scan in 248ms
Finished 10 iterations of set scan in 0ms
```

First point to note: Python's no slouch at either. 1/4 second on an old laptop to scan 10 million list elements isn't bad. But it's still a linear scan.

Python sets are in a different class. If you take the `// 1000` out of `time_since()`, you'll see that Python scans a 1-million member set 10 times in under a microsecond. You'll find other set operations are also lightning fast. Wherever sets apply in Python, use them: they're fantastic.

And if you're contemplating applying the above code to much bigger lists, where performance matters, the first thing to do might be to convert `b` to a set.

Comment: Thank you, but that's a lot more code than I've used, is it more efficient?

Comment: It's more code because it gives you more options. `Counter` is pretty quick. A `set()` operation is the fastest if you're only interested in the presence or absence of each item in `a`. This being Python, you're in the wrong place if you want super-efficient. To be frank, I find efficiency is rarely an issue with Python. On the whole Python culture is more interested in clear, simple, maintainable code than top performance.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should work as well. Find the count of each element and sum those counts up

```
op = sum([a.count(j) for j in b])
```

The outputs will be

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
b = [1, 3, 6, 9]
#4
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6 , 7, 8, 9, 0]
b = [1, 3, 6, 9]
#8
```

Comment: This appears similar to @Mehrdad Pedramfar 's answer above, which was accused of being inefficient.  I don't know enough to comment if that is the case though.

Answer (score 0):

While set works for unique

List comprehension considers duplicates as well

```
a = [1,1]
b = [1,1]

count = len(set(a) & set(b)) 
count2 = sum(i in b for i in a)  
print(count, count2)
```

```
1 2

[Program finished]
```