# Getting items from a numpy matrix, that indexes are in an array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to convert a matlab code into python and I faced a code like :

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
b=[1, 4, 8]
a(b)
//output :
ans :
1   4   8
```

this actually getting indexes from b and doing

```
a.item(x) #python
```

all I'm trying to ask is that, is there any way to do it in python ?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches). Sorry for not knowing how to set a question as a duplicate of another.

Comment: @Chunpin No, that's not the same problem. Also, `a(b)` gives `ans = 1  2  6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use numpy

- First flatten your `2D` array into `1D`
- Then use the index in `b` to find data in `a`
- Note: index in `python` starts from `0` `matlab` is `1`, so you need to
  reduce the indices in b by 1

```
    import numpy as np

    a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
    a = a.flatten()
    b = np.array([1, 4, 8])
    
    print(a[b-1])

    #array([1, 4, 8])
```

Comment: MATLABs linear indexing uses column major order, whereas your solution uses row major order. Unfortunately, the example given in the question is already wrong on that part.

Comment: @HansHirse  What do you mean by the given exemple is wrong on that part? Thought that was the same result he wanted to reproduce in python? not just an exemple

Comment: Please see my comment on the question: `a(b)` returns `1  2  6`, and not `1  4  8` as stated by the questioner. So, in the end, it's not clear, if the author wants to mimic the (correct) MATLAB functioning (column-major order indexing), or the given row-major order indexing, which then wouldn't be the proper MATLAB way.

Answer (score 2):

Attention: At the time of writing this answer, the example given in the question is wrong. `a(b)` would result in:

```matlab
ans =
   1   2   6
```

The provided MATLAB code uses [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2), which uses column-major order, whereas the stated `a.item(x)` Python function uses row-major order.

The [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) MATLAB function can convert linear indices to array indices. A similar `numpy` function is [`unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html).

Let's have a look at the following example code. Attention: Python uses 0-based indexing whereas MATLAB uses 1-based indexing.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])
b = np.array([0, 3, 7])

c = a[np.unravel_index(b, a.shape, 'F')]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

[[10 20 30]
 [40 50 60]
 [70 80 90]]

[0 3 7]

[10 20 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

In an Octave session:

```
>> a=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
a =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

>> b=[1, 4, 8]
b =

   1   4   8

>> a(b)
ans =

   1   2   6
```

This isn't the kind of behavior that I recall getting in MATLAB, but then I'm not in the habit of using index values greater than the dimensions.  Evidently it is picking the items in a flattened matrix

```
>> reshape(a,1,9)
ans =

   1   4   7   2   5   8   3   6   9

>> reshape(a,1,9)(b)
ans =

   1   2   6
```

In Python/numpy indexing is done with `[]` instead of `()`.  It is also 0 based, not 1.

```
In [56]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)                                                                
In [57]: a                                                                                               
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [58]: b=[0,3,7]                                                                                       
In [59]: a.ravel(order='F')[b]                                                                           
Out[59]: array([1, 2, 6])
In [60]: a.ravel(order='F')                                                                              
Out[60]: array([1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9])
```

To get the same values in `numpy` I had to specfify `order F` when flattening the array.  That way it 'scans' the values in the column major order that MATLAB uses.

Without the `order F`, the default scan order is row major:

```
In [61]: a.ravel()                                                                                       
Out[61]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [62]: a.ravel()[b]                                                                                    
Out[62]: array([1, 4, 8])
```

I could also get the order F when initially reshaping `a`:

```
In [67]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3,order='F')                                                      
In [68]: a                                                                                               
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
In [69]: a.flat[b]                                                                                       
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 6])
```

===

In MATLAB/Octave, we can get the 2d indices with:

```
>> [r,c] = ind2sub([3,3],b)
r =

   1   1   2

c =

   1   2   3

>> a(1,1), a(1,2), a(2,3)
ans =  1
ans =  2
ans =  6
```

The same unraveling in `numpy` (applied to the order F version of `a`):

```
In [75]: np.unravel_index(b, (3,3))                                                                      
Out[75]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 1]))
In [76]: a[_]                    # using the Out[75] line as index                                                                        
Out[76]: array([1, 2, 6])
In [77]: a[0,0],a[1,0],a[2,1]            # equivalently                                                                
Out[77]: (1, 2, 6)
```