# How can i find the number of different characters between two lists in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
A:[2 1 2 6 6 7 1 7 5 9 2 6 6 6 6 6 1 0 5 8 8 7 8 1 7 5 4 9 2 9 4 7 6 8 9 4 3]

B:[2 8 2 6 6 7 1 9 8 5 2 2 6 6 6 6 1 0 5 2 8 7 3 4 7 5 4 9 2 9 4 7 6 8 9 4 3]
```

I want to find the number of same characters and print it in PYTHON. How can i do that?
It should also test if the character is the same position with the other list.
I am new in Python Can you help?

Comment: Pls post actual valid Python data structures! Also show the exact desired output for the shown input. And most of all, show your own attempt and where you're stuck.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: What would be a valid answer? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How would the algorithm know if something was the same position or not, if it was wrong?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.   Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Does [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches) answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

You can [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) whether each element is equal. Equal is `True` or `1`:

```
count = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(A, B))
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) creates a sequence of pairs, `(A[0], B[0])`, `(A[1], B[1])`, `(A[2], B[2])`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` the two lists to get a list of corresponding item pairs, and then count how many of them have two equal items:

```py
num_equal = len([z for z in zip(a,b) if z[0] == z[1]])
```