# how to combine same matching items in a 1d list and make it as 2d list

Tags: python

Combine same items in a 1d list and make it as 2d list.
I can do this using `for` loops and `if` condition. But i want to know if there is any pythonic way to do this.

Input List:

```
 lis = ['computer', 'science', 'math', 'science', 'biology', 'math', 'computer', 'math']
```

output should be:

```
[['computer', ' computer'], ['science', 'science'], ['math', 'math', 'math'], ['biology'] ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: @Daweed that is not at all related... There are no two input lists in this question

Comment: @Daweed. How are the two related? Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: When you say "I can write a for loop", actually write the loop next time.

Comment: @badhusha, Try this [[x] * lis.count(x) for x in set(lis)]

Comment: Guys i just want to combine the same items in a list, i think my input list and sample output explained it clearly.

Comment: @modnar that's highly inefficient...

Comment: @badhushamuhammed your question is clear. It already has been answered in the link at the top of the page

Comment: yah i got it, im just asking is there any pythonic way to do this, rater than using loop and if