# Compare two objects within a class

Tags: python, class, methods, compare, instance

I was stuck in this question. I have done most of the parts but the last part in which we were supposed to compare it, I was stuck in that part could help me up with this in python.
A class called `Actor` is designed to model a movie’s actor. It contains three instance variables: `name` (String), `dateofBirth` (String), and `gender` (char of either 'm' or 'f').

The requirements for this class arre:

- There should be getter and setter function for all instance variables.
- Actor also performs in movies so make a list of the movie for each actor and store the names of the movie in it.
- There should be methods `DisplayActor` which displays all the actor data along with the movies.
- For an actor, add `AddMovie` function which adds movie name in the list.
- Add one more function named `CompareActor` that compares the two objects of actor class and find if they have worked together in the same movie.
- This function will return the list of the same movies.

I have attached my code below.

```py
class Actor:
    def __init__(self,name,dateofBirth,gender):
       self._name = name
        self._dateofBirth = dateofBirth
        self._gender = gender
        self._movies = []
    def set_name(self,name):
        self._name = name
    def set_dateofBirth(self,dateofBirth):
        self._dateofBirth= dateofBirth 
    def set_gender(self,gender):
      self._gender = gender 
    def get_name(self):
       return self._name
    def get_dateofBirth(self):
       return self._dateofBirth
    def get_gender(self):
            return self._gender
    def addmovies(self,movies):
        self._movies.append(movies)
    def DisplayActor(self):
        print("Name of Actor=",str(self._name),"DOB=",str(self._dateofBirth),"Gender=",str(self._gender),"Movies=",str(self._movies))
    
def main():
  act1 = Actor("Fallon","22 january","m")
  act1.addmovies("Deadpool")
  act1.addmovies("Avengers")
  act1.addmovies("Hell Boy")
  act1.DisplayActor()
    
  act2 = Actor("John","3 January","m")
  act2.addmovies("Hell boy")
  act2.addmovies("The Bons Collections")
  act2.addmovies("Nemo")
  act2.DisplayActor()
        
    main()
```

Comment: Hello there, welcome to Stackoverflow. To get most of the community help, I first suggest you to reedit your post in a manner that allow better understanding of your issue. For example, write a code of your attempt, so other might debug it and provide you a hint. Also care about punctuation marks and English writing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips.I have attached my attempt above

Comment: Great! I see only the method you've mentioned is missing, namely compareActor. I suppose this method must have two arguments, self and the second actor. To find which movies they acted together, I guess you should iterate over the one actor's list of movies and compare if any is contained in the list of another. Try it out

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1388818/6682517) is about comparing two lists in python (lists of movies in your case) and it has several working answers