# Intersection needed for multiple lists without knowing the content of the list

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I want to take multiple lists and know the values that appaer in these lists with the possibility of one or more of the lists being empty.

**CASE 1:**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
c = []
d = [2, 3, 5]
```

Needed output: 5

**CASE 2:**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3]
c = [1, 3, 8]
d = []
```

Needed output: 3

Order doesn't matter.
I know I can use this if there are no empty lists ([source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches) / [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c) and set(d))
```

The problem occurs when one of the lists is empty.

Python version: 3.8

Comment: Is it mandatory that your solution should return intersection value only if one or more lists are non-empty? OR we need to simply discard the empty lists while calculation the intersection?

Comment: Ideally, if there is nothing common among non empty lists, it should return an empty set right? The issue was that if a single one is empty, it always returns an empty set. Do confirm @RVE. Thanks

Comment: Only the empty lists needed to discarded. You'r solution works like a charm, thx!

Answer (score 4):

Lets use a list comprehension with `set.intersection` -

The list comprehension checks if the length of the list is greater than 0 and then uses it to find an intersection using `set.intersection`. The * operator unpacks this list of sets, to individual sets.

#### Case 1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
c = []
d = [2, 3, 5]

l = [a,b,c,d]
l = [set(i) for i in l if len(i)>0]
set.intersection(*l)
```

```
{5}
```

#### Case 2:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3]
c = [1, 3, 8]
d = []

l = [a,b,c,d]
l = [set(i) for i in l if len(i)>0]
set.intersection(*l)
```

```
{3}
```

Comment: How you are considering the MUST presence of one or more empty lists in this solution?

Comment: Its not a must presence. its a condition that is applied to filter out any if they exist.

Comment: When I have all liss empty I get this error: descriptor 'intersection' of 'set' object needs an argument.
I solved it by adding a check if len(l) > 0

Answer (score 1):

You use `filter()` to remove empty lists and then convert your `list` to `set()` objects using `map()` and do the intersection as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
c = []
d = [2, 3, 5]

my_list = [a, b, c, d]

my_result = set.intersection(*map(set, filter(bool, my_list)))
# where `my_result` holds the value: 
#    {5}
```