# Get all elements from a ul class and compare to a text file (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-behave

Just as the title implies I'm actually trying to get all the `li` elements from a dropdown field and actually be able to compare those results to the ones from an specific .txt file.

The html/DOM contains this kind of list

```html
< div id = "ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn" class = "chosen-container groups-are-selectable show-selected-in-list chosen-container-multi modified-chzn chosen-container-active" style = "width: 291px;" > <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-field">
        <input type="text" value=" " class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 266px;"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop" style="left: 0px; width: 291px; top: 29px;">
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_g_0" class="group-result active-result child-matched" title="AA - AEROBICS">AA - AEROBICS</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_1" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AABD - BODYSHAPING WITH CORY EVERSON">AABD - BODYSHAPING WITH CORY EVERSON</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_2" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AABP - Cory Everson's Gotta Sweat">AABP - Cory Everson's Gotta Sweat</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_3" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AABS - Bodyshaping">AABS - Bodyshaping</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_4" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AACF - Crunch Fitness">AACF - Crunch Fitness</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_5" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AACJ - City Jam">AACJ - City Jam</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_6" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AADA - GETTING FIT WITH DENISE AUSTIN">AADA - GETTING FIT WITH DENISE AUSTIN</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_7" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AAFA - Fitness America Tour">AAFA - Fitness America Tour</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_8" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="AAKI - KIANA'S FLEX APPEAL">AAKI - KIANA'S FLEX APPEAL</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_g_9" class="group-result active-result child-matched" title="ABB - ESPN Radio Baseball">ABB - ESPN Radio Baseball</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_10" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBAS - MLB All Star Game">ABBAS - MLB All Star Game</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_11" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBDC - Series Del Caribe">ABBDC - Series Del Caribe</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_12" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBDS - MLB Division Series">ABBDS - MLB Division Series</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_13" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBLC - MLB League Championships">ABBLC - MLB League Championships</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_14" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBMA - MLB Meet the Stars">ABBMA - MLB Meet the Stars</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_15" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBML - MLB Regular">ABBML - MLB Regular</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_16" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBMS - MLB Specials">ABBMS - MLB Specials</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_17" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBSN - MLB Sunday Night Baseball">ABBSN - MLB Sunday Night Baseball</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_18" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBWB - World Baseball Classic">ABBWB - World Baseball Classic</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_19" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABBWS - MLB World Series">ABBWS - MLB World Series</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_g_20" class="group-result active-result child-matched" title="ABK - Deportes Radio Basketball">ABK - Deportes Radio Basketball</li>
            <li id="ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn_o_21" class="active-result group-option" style="" title="ABKAS - NBA All Star Game">ABKAS - NBA All Star Game</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing I have so far (since I'm quite a noob at Selenium and Python), is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id='ProgramCategoriesAndCodes_chzn']//ul[@class='chosen-results']

list_elem = elem.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for li in list_elem:
     text = li.text
     print(text)
```

I know that print doesn't actually serves any purpose at all but I'm lost here on how to actually achieve what I asked in first place :(

The actual text file contains info like this one:

```
AEROBICS
              AE - AEROBICS
              AE - BODYBUILDING
              AE - MISCELLANEOUS
AMERICAS CLUB SOCCER
              SOAM - ARGENTINE SOCCER
              SOAM - ARGENTINE SOCCER RPT
              SOAM - BRASILEIRAO SUB 20
              SOAM - BRASILEIRAO SUB 20 RPT
              SOAM - BRAZILIAN CHAMPIONSHIP
              SOAM - BRAZILIAN CHAMPIONSHIP RPT
              SOAM - COPA DO BRAZIL
              SOAM - COPA DO BRAZIL RPT
              SOAM - COPA MEXICO
              SOAM - COPA MEXICO RPT
              SOAM - COPA SAO PAULO JUNIOR
              SOAM - LIGA FPD DE COSTA RICA
              SOAM - LIGA MEXICANA
              SOAM - LIGA MEXICANA RPT
              SOAM - MAJOR LEAGUE SOCCER
              SOAM - MAJOR LEAGUE SOCCER RPT
              SOAM - USA SOCCER
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Kind Regards.

Comment: Check here how to compare two lists in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches

Comment: @vitaliis thanks man, will try this along with the solution that gaurav indicated below!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are having problem to how to match with txt file because you are able to extract all text from `li` elements so i will suggest you to make list of your txt file like this

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    txt_list = f.read().splitlines() # it will give list of each line
    print(list(x.strip() for x in txt_list)) # it will strip the white space from start and end
```

now you have two lists one form li and other from txt now you can use python `in` or `set` as your requirement.

other thing can be use is you simply match your txt from li to text file string
name = 'AE - AEROBICS'

```
name = 'AE - AEROBICS'
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    txt_str = f.read() # return txt file as str
    print(txt_str.find(name)) $ return index if present otherwise -1
```